# Using a 3g usb dongle as Cisco router access point

Tags: linux, cisco, routing, bridge-router

We have an office opening, and we aren't going to have comms into the building when management want the building to open.

Our only option (I think) Is to try and hook up a 3/4g dongle to something to act as the access point, and send all the traffic via that. The model of router we use wont support the usb dongle, so we need some sort of 'bridge'

My idea was to build a Linux box, plug the dongle into that and then via the Ethernet ports plug the router in.

We need the Cisco router in the equation as we create VPN connections over that back to head office. My question is will this work?

Comment: If you really have to go the 3g/4g route why not get an actual router that supports it like an 819 or RV215W?  Why make it more complex than it has to be?  And management is opening an office and doesn't want to spend the quite cheap funds to do it even semi-right?

Comment: We are moving the office from one building into another, so all the existing kit is being utilized, so we cant spend any money on it. Plus our main network guy has had issues in the past putting in new router models without testing them, so its not really an option. Its hopefully only going to be used for a month at the most

Comment: OK, then if your question is can you route LAN traffic through the Cisco router out the Linux box using a 4g card/dongle...sure, I don't see why not.  But everyone's situation is somewhat unique, so you'll have to decide if it will work for you and your team.

Comment: i think we might be on a bit of a fail with this anyway. The dongle seems to have been given an ip address in a private range, not a public one, so i dont think we'll be able to create a vpn tunnel to it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never ended up using this, we just setup ICS on one pc, installed client vpn on the others and used that as the access point. Not ideal but it worked short term

Answer (score 0):

www.cradlepoint.com

Snag one of those devices - seems to be the most widely deployed solution that I've seen for your use case.

http://www.cradlepoint.com/products/branch-office-retail-pos/cba750b-mobile-3g-4g-broadband-adapter